# doctrine:schema:update --force does not work is it APC?

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, apc

I've created 2 new entities, and when running command 'php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql' I get the message 'Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.'

I've tried clearing cache, and removing contents of the doctrine folder for orm, which was a couple of suggestions on this forum.  Still no joy.  I'm using APC cache settings on my config are as below.

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
 dbal:
    driver:   "%database_driver%"
    host:     "%database_host%"
    port:     "%database_port%"
    dbname:   "%database_name%"
    user:     "%database_user%"
    password: "%database_password%"
    charset:  UTF8



orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    auto_mapping: true
    metadata_cache_driver: apc
    result_cache_driver: apc
    query_cache_driver: apc
```

Comment: Have you registered the bundle with the new entities in `AppKernel.php`?

Comment: What happens with the validate command?

Comment: [Mapping]  OK - The mapping files are correct.
[Database] OK - The database schema is in sync with the mapping files.

Comment: Are you sure you cleaned cache and executed your update command with the right env=? attribute? - so, depending on your environment you have to set this: app/console cache:clear --env=prod (just as an example for prod)

Comment: Another common problem is trying to mix mapping formats(annotations and yml).  Make sure you have the expected files under Resources/config/doctrine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be this sounds idiotic but i cant comment so i will say it here, 
Can we see at least one of your entities? may be you have the wrong annotations.
Like forgetting to write

> /**  * @ORM\Table()  * @ORM\Entity  */

Personally i use

> php app/console generate:doctrine:entity

to make sure all the basics annotations get included

Comment: good point, the annotations were not included - not sure why I used 'php app/console generate:doctrine:entity'

Comment: Glad i helped,  did this answer solve your problem? if thats the case, please mark it as the solution =)

Comment: Does anyone know why the @ORM was missing when I created my entities, maybe a setting, doesn't normally leave them out?